# I have a really slow page, how can I figure out of it's the M, V, or C? What kind of timing mechanism would be accurate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization, benchmarking

The controller makes a few calls to the model, then it returns some data to the view. The view actually, sadly, (it's not my fault), contains a ton of inline queries and more calls to the Model, yeah I know. Anyways I am tasked with optimizing this really slow page and I am trying to figure out how I can tell which thing is taking the most time. I was just going to put a timer at the start and the end of each 'thing' that the page does and output them to a log with the line number or something. But not sure what the most accurate way to do this is.

```
//in controller
StartTimer();
var something = model.something.getsomething(someID);
StopTimerAndLog(3); //line number

<!-- in view -->
<%StartTimer();
var something = model.somethingelse.getanotherthing(someotherID);
StopTimerAndLog(2);%>
```

so on and so forth...

Then the question remains about what timing mechanism to use, I'm sure there must be a question about this already. But I don't know if my situation makes anything unique or not... any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to measure like this, I would use [the StopWatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

```
var watch = new StopWatch();
watch.Start();
var something = model.something.getSomething(someID);
watch.Stop();

var time = watch.Elapsed;
```

If you want something really detailed and without writing any extra code...I would suggest the use of a Profiler. It will give you details about exactly what is taking so long and why. My personal favorite is [RedGate's ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

Comment: thanks for the quick response, this gives me something to try right now while I wait for more feedback to trickle in

Comment: I strongly second Justin's latter recommendation.  Using a profiler like ANTS or dotTrace is a much better approach than printf debugging.

Comment: +1: @Justin Niessner - just curious if Profiler can be used for proper Load Testing an app? Or any recommended tools?

Comment: @VoodooChild - It can't be used alone for Load Testing, no. Profilers typically run in the background and monitor the app as it runs. It doesn't actually perform any operations in the application. You can, however, pair it with the Load Testing features in Visual Studio to monitor your code's performance under load that way.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: thanks :), and what "Load Testing features in Visual Studio" do you speak of?

Comment: @VoodooChild - Most people don't realize that, depending on what version of Visual Studio you are using, you can create a Test Project. A Test project may consist of the typical Unit Tests but can also contain Load Tests which allows you to provide a script to hit your application, configure the load, run the test, and store the results in a SQL Server Express database. Here's a quick writeup: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/13e16f83-4cf2-4c9d-b75b-aa67fc309108/load-testing-aspnet-appl.aspx

Comment: @Justin Niessner: thanks again. From the link it is the `the Ultimate Edition` that has these features - that edition also has a pretty big price tag :)

Comment: @VoodooChild - That's why you have to be very kind to your employer. ;-)